# Using a broadcast receiver for alarm manager and notification

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I created an alarm clock app that plays music when the alarm goes off. I set up a notification as well. I am using a broadcast receiver but it is ended when I leave the activity that created it and plays the music. My first question is, is a broadcast receiver the best way to handle this and is implementing a receiver in the manifest the only way to eliminate my problem of losing my receiver. When I leave the activity that created the app, I receive an error because I haven't unregistered the receiver. My first app and needing some advice. I can provide the code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the inbuilt alarm to trigger using a pendingintent. That way you don't need a broadcast receiver.

Comment: Do you have any examples of using the builtin alarm? Most examples that I have seen use the Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: Here's an example of triggering an alarm for midnight. You can set the time as you want. 
Intent intentToFire = new Intent();
intentToFire.setClassName(packageName, className);
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance(); 
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0); 
time.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
alarmScheduleIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentToFire, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmScheduleManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis, alarmScheduleIntent);

Comment: Thanks for the example. It definitely helps.